# Adding an overlay in a facetted map using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

An image is worth a thousand words:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, I have created a facetted maps with ggplot, but each facet is lacking the countries which do not have any value for that particular variable (although that does not explain grey countries like the ones in var3 facet). My guess is that adding a new geometry layer below would fix this, but unfortunately I do not have any clue to fix this.

**Desired output:**

What I would like to achieve is that all countries were displayed in all facets, and in case they do not have a value for that particular value should be outputted in another colour (grey, for example). By doing that, the world map would always be complete instead of presenting holes which makes it really weird to read.

I would like to achieve something like this, but for every facet (and obviously values and colors would have to change):

[image]

**That's the code I've used so far:**

```
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

world = readOGR(dsn = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ccamara/fc26d8bb7e777488b446fbaad1e6ea63/raw/a6f69b6c3b4a75b02858e966b9d36c85982cbd32/countries.geojson")


# Load dataframe.
df = read.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ccamara/fc26d8bb7e777488b446fbaad1e6ea63/raw/519c6199c9fc24df87bb6ca0bfcd0413db6e3617/sample-dataframe-grouped.csv")

world.t = tidy(world, region = "name")

# join with the original file's data
world.t = left_join(world.t, world@data, by = c("id" = "name"))

# join with df
world.t = left_join(world.t, df, by = c("iso_a2" = "country_code"))

ggplot(data = world.t, aes(long, lat, fill = value, group = group)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  #scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = "Reds")+
  geom_polygon() +
  geom_path(colour = "black", lwd = 0.05) +
  coord_equal() +
  ggtitle("Countries without values are not displayed") +
  labs(fill = "amount") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

Also, after reading [this other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188337/how-to-overlay-a-polyshape-to-faceted-maps-in-r-with-ggplot), I made a slight adaptation to it, but the new layer is displayed over the previous ones instead of below them.

```
map.1 = ggplot(data = world.t,
       aes(long, lat, fill = value, group = group)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  geom_polygon() +
  geom_path(colour = "black", lwd = 0.05) +
  coord_equal() +
  ggtitle("New layer hides everything else") +
  labs(fill = "amount") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())


map.1 + geom_polygon(data=world.t,
            aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), lwd = 0.01, fill = "blue", inherit.aes = F)
```

[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want all missing countries to be blue and all others to be on the red-orange colour scale. Have you considered plotting the blue countries first and then the others?

Comment: Thanks for answering, @sebastian-c. I have updated the description and I hope it is clearer now. Regarding your proposal, I understand that it may work, but unfortunately I do not have a clue on how to do that (never done something like that before -in fact this code here is the furthest I've ever gone with maps and ggplot).

Comment: Do not make a map.1 + overlay polygon, but do all in one go, running the  `fill = "blue"` layer prior to running `fill = value` layer. or make the map.1 with just overlay layer and add the `fill = value` layer last

Comment: Do you need that last 'NA' facet or is that just an artifact?

Comment: No, I don't need last NA facet :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your code to capture the world map at the beginning:

```
base_world = tidy(world, region = "name") 

world.t = base_world

# join with the original file's data
world.t = left_join(world.t, world@data, by = c("id" = "name"))

# join with df
world.t = left_join(world.t, df, by = c("iso_a2" = "country_code"))

world.t <- filter(world.t, !is.na(variable))

ggplot(data = world.t[!is.na(world.t$value),],
               aes(long, lat, fill = value, group = group)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") +
  geom_polygon(data=base_world[base_world$order,],
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), 
               lwd = 0.01, fill = "grey", inherit.aes = F) + #Put original map in
  geom_polygon() + #Draw data on top
  geom_path(colour = "black", lwd = 0.05) +
  coord_equal() +
  ggtitle("Now it looks a little better") +
  labs(fill = "amount") +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Works great (as you already know)

Comment: No worries - thanks for very easy to follow example.

Comment: Stupid question from a newbie: do you know how could I display poligons' borders like in the other layer? Apparently `geom_polygon(data=base_world[base_world$order,],
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), 
               lwd = 0.01, fill = "grey", inherit.aes = F)` is ignoring `geom_path(colour = "black", lwd = 0.05)` (which I assume it's the purpose of `inherit.aes = F`)

Comment: You could add another polygon for the lines: `geom_polygon(data = base_world[base_world$order,], aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),  
                 colour = "black", fill = NA, lwd = 0.05, inherit.aes = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks even better now!